# How to prevent overlap of cells in ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've been working on a locally hosted notebook for a while with no problems. However, I recently re-opened the notebook and found all of my cells to be overlapping, as shown in the image below:

[image]

If I move the cells up and down again they seem to re-align correctly. The only change I can think of that may have caused this was that I recently updated my anaconda package. All of the output to the console appears normal to me.

```
2014-10-10 08:22:45.531 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/uname/.ipython/profile_default'
2014-10-10 08:22:45.535 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2014-10-10 08:22:45.726 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/uname/cwd
2014-10-10 08:22:45.727 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
2014-10-10 08:22:45.727 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2014-10-10 08:22:45.727 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
2014-10-10 08:23:00.197 [NotebookApp] Kernel started: fa1fcfaf-c04f-4af0-a8da-6199a5e1d7ca
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

**System Info:**

- Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)
- Mac OS X Version 10.9.4
- Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.13 beta (64-bit)

Answer (score 6):

Downgrade chrome. V39.x is supposed to be dev. Bug is apparently fixed on chrome canary.

Comment: FYI: The current beta channel build (Version 39.0.2171.36 beta) has fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine in **Firefox**.
Downgrading chrome might cause some security vulnerabilities to be exposed.